# Tizen AVPlay Player Can’t Play MP4 PLAYER_ERROR_CONNECTION_FAILED

Tags: javascript, tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-studio

I need to play a mp4 video and the source of video is on my cloud server. I try to play using video tag `<video></video>` it’s work correctly the video is playing. But when i try to using AVPlay API it’s throw the error PLAYER_ERROR_CONNECTION_FAILED when calling to prepare. This is my code

```
    webapis.avplay.open("https://preskripsi.com/assets/net.mp4");
    webapis.avplay.setDisplayRect(0, 0, 1920, 1080);
    webapis.avplay.setDisplayMethod(
      "PLAYER_DISPLAY_MODE_AUTO_ASPECT_RATIO"
    );
    webapis.avplay.setListener(listener);
    webapis.avplay.prepareAsync(function () {
      webapis.avplay.play();
    });
```

i’ve been put this on config.xml but it’s still not working

```
<access origin="*" subdomains="true"></access>
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/internet"/>
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/tv.window"/>
```

and i try to put this on config.xml

```
<tizen:privilege name="http://developer.samsung.com/privilege/avplay" />
```

but still not working

please help me, thanks.

Comment: I would guess that your resource from the cloud server will likely have to be CORS-enabled, but that currently doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: i've try to play on my localhost using xampp its still not played bro. i try to check on my web console log its no issue with CORS. how to make sure that?

Answer (score 0):

Sample code looks fine.
I didn't meet the problem as you, but basing on my experience it looks environment issue,may be network.
you can also check your content with Sample AVPLAY wgt:
https://github.com/SamsungDForum/PlayerAVPlay/blob/master/PlayerAVPlay/

Comment: ok i will try it, but before that i will tell if my issue is based on environment issue may be network connection, why when i change the avplay api into html5 video the video is successfully playing without issue